# Python 3.2 logging with config file results in KeyError: 'formatters' on Raspbian

Tags: python, logging, raspberry-pi, python-3.2, keyerror

I equipped my Python application with logging capability and it works flawlessly on my Windows system with Python 3.4. But when I deploy the application on my Raspberry Pi with Raspbian and Python 3.2, I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aurora/aurora_websocket.py", line 265, in <module>
    logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/logging/config.py", line 70, in fileConfig
    formatters = _create_formatters(cp)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/logging/config.py", line 106, in _create_formatters
    flist = cp["formatters"]["keys"]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/configparser.py", line 941, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'formatters'
```

The logging.conf file (encoded in UTF-8 without BOM):

```
[loggers]
keys=root,simpleExample

[handlers]
keys=screen

[formatters]
keys=simple,complex

[logger_root]
level=NOTSET
handlers=screen

[logger_simpleExample]
level=DEBUG
handlers=screen
qualname=simpleExample
propagate=0

[handler_screen]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=complex
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatter_simple]
format=%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=

[formatter_complex]
format=%(asctime)s - %(levelname)-8s - <%(module)s : %(lineno)d> - %(message)s
datefmt=
```

The logging configuration is loaded in a simple one-liner:

```
logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')
```

I'm at a loss here, since, as mentioned above already, my application works fine on Windows, but fails on the RPi.

Comment: Are you sure that you have formatters in your config file? It seems that it is trying to access it and there isn't any field called like this. Or is it raised by libraries that are not implemented by you?

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, because of your comment I revisited the issue once again and finally found the problem. I posted the solution below.

Answer (score 5):

Well, this didn't last long... Turns out, I've been running my application on the RPi from a different working directory. Consequently, the file path to the logging.conf file is interpreted incorrectly relative to the differing working directory. Unfortunately, the logging library tries to continue on with non-existent files and doesn't throw a useful exception in that case.